# how to fix'Too few arguments to function Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client::buildClient()' when use 'GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub'

Tags: laravel, git, github, guzzle, guzzle6

I make a web application for the management of the educational establishment with laravel, so I have to make a collaborative workspace.

The idea that I find is to work with GitHub repository, after a search in the web I find 'GrahamCampbell / Laravel-GitHub'.
I do the installation like documentation, but when I test I have the following error:

```
Too few arguments to function Http \ Adapter \ Guzzle6 \ Client :: buildClient (), 
0 passed in C: \ Users \ Fehmi \ Dropbox \ GRASP \ vendor \ php-http \ guzzle6-adapter \ src \ Client.php on line 31 and exactly 1 expected "
```

```
use GrahamCampbell\GitHub\Facades\GitHub;
class GitController extends Controller
{
   public function FuncName ()
   {
     dd(GitHub::me()->organizations());
   }
}
```

The result that I have is

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Too few arguments to function Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client::buildClient(), 0 passed in C:\Users\Fehmi\Dropbox\GRASP\vendor\php-http\guzzle6-adapter\src\Client.php on line 31 and exactly 1 expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use the latest [`php-http/guzzle6-adapter`](https://github.com/php-http/guzzle6-adapter/) version.

Only the [one from May 2016 has a line 31](https://github.com/php-http/guzzle6-adapter/blame/666cb6b621b33caaaec6bfe264a494f17999be53/src/Client.php#L31) with  `$client = static::buildClient();`, and it had an [issue fixed in PR 32](https://github.com/php-http/guzzle6-adapter/pull/32) to allow calling the [`buildClient()` with no parameters](https://github.com/php-http/guzzle6-adapter/commit/594cd47fb9af5c217f0e63c4e8f7602da88a368a).

[`GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub`](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub) only imposes [a guzzle6 version](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub/blob/eb61a055a03a5151cbbeedb3b0a357c4eeb2640d/composer.json#L26) as a [range between 1.0 (included) and 2.0](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-).
Maybe using `^2.0` or at least `^1.1` might help.